# Access local network via Synology OpenVPN

Tags: vpn, openvpn, network-attached-storage, synology

I'm trying to access my LAN via a Synology NAS with the OpenVPN package.

My router IP is `192.168.1.1` and my Synology NAS IP is `192.168.1.100`.

They are both connected to a managed Netgear switch whose IP is `192.168.1.10`.

I setup the OpenVPN package on the NAS with the dynamic IP range set as `192.168.2.0 ~ 192.168.2.255`.

So the LAN is on x.x.**1**.x and the VPN dynamic range is on x.x.**2**.x.

I opened the OpenVPN port on the router and I can successfully connect from the outside to the VPN using my public IP.

I can see from the VPN dashboard that the device get assigned an IP such as `192.168.2.6`. However I can't ping anything on the LAN and neither from the LAN to the connected device.

I also tried disabling the NAS firewall to no avail.

I'm reading on the argument and I, if I understood correctly, need to make a route so that both subnets can communicate.

On the NAS there's an **IP Routing Table** with the following settings:

```
+---------------------+-------------+-----------------+--------+-----------+
| Network destination | Gateway     | Netmask         | Metric | Interface |
+---------------------+-------------+-----------------+--------+-----------+
| default             | 192.168.1.1 | 0.0.0.0         | 0      | LAN1      |
| 192.168.1.0         | 0.0.0.0     | 255.255.255.0   | 0      | LAN1      |
| 192.168.2.0         | 192.168.2.2 | 255.255.255.0   | 0      | VPN       |
| 192.168.2.2         | 0.0.0.0     | 255.255.255.255 | 0      | VPN       |
+---------------------+-------------+-----------------+--------+-----------+
```

This was all done automatically from the NAS. It seems to be complete to me but since I can't ping or access the NAS from the device I'm sure I'm probably missing something.

Comment: did you resolve this issue? facing similar issues with DS218j. We have about 20 internal subnets. I am only able to ping devices connected to the same subnet as the Synology in the internal network. The traffic is not going beyond that